# Importing HTML/CSS into InDesign layout?

Tags: adobe-indesign, html, layout, xml, newspaper

I'm trying to convert an HTML page that has bold text / css in it into an InDesign document so I can lay it out for print in a newspaper in PDF format.

Here is a link to the HTML page:  http://ronchambers.com/misc/bwm/test.php

When I highlight the entire page and copy/paste into InDesign it doesn't copy over all the formatting.

I'm a programmer, so should I convert the HTML into XML and somehow import this into InDesign?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You can copy, paste into Word. Save, then import the Word file into InDesign retaining styles.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use Chrome to save as html.  Then open the html file with Word.  Then save the word file as docx.  After this I "placed" it into InDesign.  Worked.  I changed all my html fonts from "px" to "pt" to make them work better through the process.  Same with "line-height".